# biblatex double last name issues with imported zotero in overleaf

Tags: biblatex, citing, overleaf, zotero

I am writing a large text in overleaf using an import zotero biblatex. Whenever I want to cite a double last name like 'van Garderen' than the 'van' disappears. There are some questions on this platform about it, but never with an importet zotero biblatex, and thus I have not managed to fix it.

the code for the bibliography is as follows in the cls file:

```
\RequirePackage[style=authoryear, isbn=false,url=false,natbib=true, uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

And in the reference tex file:

```
\printbibliography[title=References]
```

the imported zotero references look as follows:

```
@article{van_garderen_methodology_2021,
    title = {A methodology for attributing the role of climate change in extreme events: a global spectrally nudged storyline},
    volume = {21},
    rights = {All rights reserved},
    url = {https://nhess.copernicus.org/articles/21/171/2021/},
    doi = {10.5194/nhess-21-171-2021},
    pages = {171--186},
    number = {1},
    journaltitle = {Natural Hazards and Earth System Sciences},
    author = {van Garderen, L. and Feser, F. and Shepherd, T. G.},
    date = {2021},
}
```

The `uniquename=false` is needed to make sure first names are not used. However with or without does not change the issue at hand.

Because I am importing from zotero I cannot add brackets to the .bib files, and according to the resources on this platform the organisation of the author names is correct to prevent the double last name issues. Still the citation looks like *Garderen (2021)* instead of *van Garderen (2021)*. There is not difference if I cite with `\citep{}` or with `\autocite{}`.

Does anybody have any advice how I can correct this?

Comment: Use the `useprefix` package option.

Comment: perfect, thanks! if you put it as an answer below, I can vote it up and close the question. Thanks, good to know it is such an easy fix! :)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to type up a quick answer here? Surprisingly I did not manage to find a good duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the  `useprefix` key to switch the printing of the `van` on and off.